# Running Qt for Embedded Linux 4.8.5 Examples

Tags: qt, qt4

I've installed Qt for Embedded Linux (Qt 4.8.5) using the [official installation guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-install.html). However, when I run any of the installed examples in QtCreator 3.0.1, I get the following error:

```
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused
No Qt for Embedded Linux server appears to be running.
If you want to run this program as a server,
add the "-qws" command-line option.
```

And if I run using the `-qws` option, I get:

```
QScreenLinuxFb::connect: Permission denied Error opening framebuffer
/dev/fb0 The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

From google results, I can see that it's related to permission settings, probably with framebuffer device (/dev/fb0). Following is the output of `ls -al /dev/fb0` on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS system:

```
$ ls -al /dev/fb0
crw-rw---- 1 root video 29, 0 Apr 21 22:43 /dev/fb0
```

I've added the currently logged in user to the `video` group that `/dev/fb0` belongs to. Still I'm getting the `permission denied` error.

If I run the `/examples/qws/framebuffer` example using `sudo`, I'm getting the following output:

```
The framebuffer device was opened successfully.

Fixed screen info:
    id:          inteldrmfb
    smem_start:  0xc0073000
    smem_len:    5763072
    type:        0
    type_aux:    0
    visual:      2
    xpanstep:    1
    ypanstep:    1
    ywrapstep:   0
    line_length: 6400
    mmio_start:  0x0
    mmio_len:    0
    accel:       0

The framebuffer device was mapped to memory successfully.

Was in graphics mode already. Skipping
Variable screen info:
    xres:           1600
    yres:           900
    xres_virtual:   1600
    yres_virtual:   900
    yoffset:        0
    xoffset:        0
    bits_per_pixel: 32
    grayscale: 0
    red:    offset: 16, length:  8, msb_right:  0
    green:  offset:  8, length:  8, msb_right:  0
    blue:   offset:  0, length:  8, msb_right:  0
    transp: offset:  0, length:  0, msb_right:  0
    nonstd:       0
    activate:     0
    height:       -1
    width:        -1
    accel_flags:  0x1
    pixclock:     0
    left_margin:  0
    right_margin: 0
    upper_margin: 0
    lower_margin: 0
    hsync_len:    0
    vsync_len:    0
    sync:         0
    vmode:        0

Frame Buffer Performance test...
        Average:   916 usecs
        Bandwidth: 6000.102 MByte/Sec
        Max. FPS:  1091.703 fps

Will draw 3 rectangles on the screen,
they should be colored red, green and blue (in that order).
  Done.
```

However, I do not see the 3 rectangles on screen.

Could someone please help outline how to run these Qt for Embedded Linux (Qt 4.8.5) examples on the Ubuntu desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using a 12.04 system only but with Qt 4.6.1.
I ran into the same issues as you and found that, when I run using -qws from console (Ctrl + Alt + F1) terminal the GUI can be seen.
When run from the GUI terminal or Qt Creator, though the window is presented, the OS's GUI (X11) overwrites the screen with its contents during screen refresh.

If you want to be able to run Qt GUI apps from Qt Creator or a GUI OS, *qvfb* needs to be running in the background.
This link throws some information on this : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvfb.html

Hope this helps !